# how to stop listening for gossiped transaction (restrict access to the TXpool)?

Tags: substrate-node-template, tx-pool

In outer node, i want to create a node that does not listen to gossiped transaction or in other words the transaction pool should not add any transaction from other peers, the only way to add transactions is done by the local node himself using [pool.submit_one()](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sc_transaction_pool/struct.Pool.html#method.submit_one) method.

PS: even when closing all the rpc ports, its still adds transactions and i assume its low level using libp2p.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, transactions are gossiped via libp2p networking. If you don't want to receive/send transactions via libp2p networking you need to [change the following code](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/15bb9c61aecf73a3a7a1853151a27587edb34b97/bin/node/cli/src/service.rs#L352-L361):

```
let (network, system_rpc_tx, tx_handler_controller, network_starter, sync_service) =
        sc_service::build_network(sc_service::BuildNetworkParams {
        config: &config,
        client: client.clone(),
        transaction_pool: transaction_pool.clone(),
        spawn_handle: task_manager.spawn_handle(),
        import_queue,
        block_announce_validator_builder: None,
        warp_sync_params: Some(WarpSyncParams::WithProvider(warp_sync)),
    })?;
```

`transaction_pool` is the thing you need to change. You will need to provide your own implementation of the [`TransactionPool` trait](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/15bb9c61aecf73a3a7a1853151a27587edb34b97/client/network/transactions/src/config.rs#L57-L70):

```
struct DummyTxPool;

impl<B> sc_network_transactions::config::TransactionPool<Block::Hash, B>
    for DummyTxPool
where
    B: BlockT,
{
    fn transactions(&self) -> Vec<(H, B::Extrinsic)> {
        // Don't propagate any transactions
        vec![]
    }

    fn hash_of(&self, tx: &B::Extrinsic) -> H {
        sp_runtime::traits::HashFor::<B>::hash_of(tx)
    }

    fn import(&self, _: B::Extrinsic) -> TransactionImportFuture {
        // We just ignore the import request.
        async { TransactionImport::None }.boxed()
    }

    fn on_broadcasted(&self, _: HashMap<H, Vec<String>>) {}

    fn transaction(&self, _: &H) -> Option<B::Extrinsic> {
        None
    }
}
```

Then you need to set `transaction_pool` to `DummyTxPool`. If you maybe want to still propagate your own local transactions, you need to modify `transactions` to return the ones you want to propagate.

Comment: so i should i use the old transaction pool everywhere else except when building the network paramters i should i pass my custom pool ? and this way i'll avoid libp2p gossiped messages

Comment: Yes exactly that is the way.

Comment: it does not work, BuildNetworkParams does not require the pool to implement sc_network_transactions::config::TransactionPool, so none of those methods are actually called

Comment: sorry i meant build_network() function not BuildNetworkParams

Comment: You are right, the `MaintainedTransactionPool` bound is wrong. `maintained_pool` could be implemented right now by doing nothing. However, I also opened a pr to use the correct bound: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13959

Comment: yeah so basically what i did was creating a wrapper around transaction_pool and implemented sc_service::TransactionPool (not to confuse it with config::TransactionPool) and created my custom behaviour (sometimes calling parent_pool whenever needed)